# Sending UUID to server without asking permission (for analytics)

Tags: ios, privacy

My Swift app is using the following piece of code to generate a unique string:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor.UUIDString
```

For analytical purposes our application sends a `PUT` request to our server using this UUID when a user presses a specific button within the app. This essentially allows us to create a table of anonymous information for analytical purposes. We hold no information about the user specifically, just a random string identifying the device (on what I believe is a per-app basis).

My question is, are we allowed to do this without asking the user's permission? I understand it is ethical to ask first before sending anonymous usage data, but does Apple restrict you physically from doing this (as in will decline app)?

The reason I am asking this question is because the usage information is especially useful to us and we don't want to scare the user by asking them for this data when it is something so basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Apple doesn't reject apps for collecting this without user's permissions. 
This is because Apple takes appropriate measures to make sure you don't permanently tag a device of a user merely by collecting the device ID.

I found this documentation helpful, which I believe you must have read already.

> The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for apps on different devices regardless of vendor.

And if you want to use it for Advertising, read this passage.

> When implementing a system for serving advertisements, use the value
>   in the advertisingIdentifier property of the ASIdentifierManager class
>   instead of this property. Use of that property requires you to follow
>   the guidelines set forth in the class discussion for the proper use of
>   that identifier. For more information, see ASIdentifierManager Class
>   Reference.

Comment: Thanks very much! I couldn't find the documentation supporting your argument so I am very grateful for your answer.